# Issues with an optimization problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

I have an expression $$Ax+By+Cz.$$ where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive constants $\ge1$. The variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negative integers. I am also given a number $T$.

I want to find the largest integer value such that it is less than $T$ and not satisfied by $Ax+By+Cz$, how can I do it without using brute force.

I can use LinearProgramming but that will give me the value that is satisfied by $Ax+By+Cz$ such that it is less than T. But I want to find the largest value which is less than T, but doesn't belong to $Ax+By+Cz$ for any value of x, y and z

Comment: Linear programming won't help you one bit since everything is an integer. Can you solve the problem if $C = 0$?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus The constants A,B, C are greater than equal to 1

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. I can get a suboptimal solution though when I use LP that will be approximate of the true solution. But the main thing is I don't want to have the answer that satisfied Ax+By+Cz but the one that is largest but less than T and also isn't given by Ax+By+Cz for any integer value of x,y and z

Comment: I suggest you first try to solve the easier $Ax+By$ case, which corresponds to $C=0$. Perhaps even start with $Ax$, i.e. $B=C=0$. That might help you solve the actual problem.

Comment: $A,B,C$ are positive integers?

Comment: See this related problem on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/largest-integer-that-cant-be-represented-as-a-non-negative-linear-combination-o)

Comment: You haven't fully defined your problem, and thus it cannot be answered in its current form.